# How to post large log results?

Tags: support, asking-questions

Is there any way of adding to a question a large amount of debug info or log results in order to get a clean Question without add it as a embedded code text?

Maybe another Stack Exchange service?

Comment: If a question needs external information storage its too big. Cut it down to the bare minimum complete example (presumably a smaller example program would create less debug information)

Comment: That would make use of Stack Overflow as a log parser/debug service. Not exactly what it is for/about.

Comment: I agree, I only want know how could be a standard way to do that.

Comment: It could be convenient when you have this error `Body is limited to 30000 characters; you entered 77171.`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It all depends on what exactly the question is. If the question is asking for debugging help and using the log files as a data source then I don't think it would be a good fit for any Stack Exchange site. It's simply too localized for that specific situation. Debugging log files of a specific application would only really be relevant for people using that specific application at that specific time.

If on the other hand, the question is asking about a good *method* to debug the log files, only a small potion of the larger file would need to be added to the post as an example of the log/file format.

When a file is too big to include into a post, think about who is going to be reading this content? Will they be willing to go through mountains and mountains of text just to understand what's going on? I believe not.

---

If you're including a large file that contains some additional information or examples of input/output data - you could always upload it to something like http://pastebin.com/ and link to it. This shouldn't be the entire question though... Don't forget to give a little explanation about the link and the content it holds so that people will be able to identify it at a glance.